# d3.js Zoom & Pan Timeline - How to Show Dynamic Timeline Range?

Tags: d3.js

I have a zoom and pan timeline built, which scales in time along the x-axis properly.  I am trying to get the real-time state of the x-axis as it is zoomed or panned.  How do I get a hold of these date_min and date_max variables?

My ultimate purpose with this interactive timeline is to get the real-time zoom/pan state, and send that state data back to a server to request data for this new time scale.

div's are in place to render the "x-min" and "x-max" but I do not know how to properly hook into the d3 axis or zoom functions to get a hold of these dynamic state variables.

Here is the x function:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2018, 1, 1)])
    .range([0, width]);
```

Here is the xAxis function:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(-height);
```

Here is the zoom function:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .xExtent([new Date(-2000, 1, 1), new Date(3000, 1, 1)])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Here is the zoomed function:

```
function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Even being able to console.log() the x-axis range would work, but I'm missing something fundamental about the way variables are bound and handled here in d3 and javascript.

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `xAxis.scale().domain()` which contains `min` and `max` values of X-axis that are currently being displayed.
I added two lines to your `zoomed()` function and it works for me:

```
function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    document.getElementById('x-min').innerHTML = xAxis.scale().domain()[0];
    document.getElementById('x-max').innerHTML = xAxis.scale().domain()[1];
}
```

For this to show, you will have to zoom the chart first.
Here is the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkL821fm/2/

**Edit:**
To update the divs only after last zoom, you can use a timeout function inside `zoomed()` with a duration such as 1000 ms. You can change it to suit your needs. One small side effect is that there will be delay (equal to the duration you have set) in updating the divs, after the last zoom.

```
lastZoomDate = new Date();
setTimeout(function() {
    updateXDiv(new Date());
  }, 1000);
```

Here, the function first checks if the graph has been zoomed again and only updates the divs if no change has occurred in the past 1000 milliseconds.

```
function updateXDiv(myDate) {
      if (lastZoomDate <= myDate) {
        document.getElementById('x-min').innerHTML = xAxis.scale().domain()[0];
        document.getElementById('x-max').innerHTML = xAxis.scale().domain()[1];
      }
    }
```

I have updated the jsfiddle to include this edit: https://jsfiddle.net/gkL821fm/3/

Comment: Thank you!  As a followup, is there a way to wait and capture the last x-axis state on mouseup? (and ignore all the intermediate values that change during a mouse drag)  Something like a 'finally' clause on the zoomed() function?  Or only triggering the .innerHTML update at the end of the UI gesture?

Comment: I have made an edit in the answer to solve your problem in the comment.